# Problem with Hello, Views: List View tutorial

Tags: android, list, listview, adapter

I've just started Android development with Eclipse, so I've been going through all the "Hello" tutorials on the Android Developers site. I have come unstuck, however, on the List View tutorial. I have tried many times to correct the problems, but I am inexperienced and whatever I do doesn't seem to work. I have copied and pasted the code directly from the site, but it still contains errors I cannot fix, so can anyone help me? Here is the code:

```
package com.hellolistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

   ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
       // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   });
 }
    }
    static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
    "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
    "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
    "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
    "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
    "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
    "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
    "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
    "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
    "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
    "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
    "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
    "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
    "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
    "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
    "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
    "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
    "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
    "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
    "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
    "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
    "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
    "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
    "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
    "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
    "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
    "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
    "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
    "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
    "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
    "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
    "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
    "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
    "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
     };
```

The XML files have all been copied straight from the tutorial at [this address](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) so they should be correct. The errors include: "The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})". Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add this:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

---

I think you are seeing bascially the same error. Here is the "import" part of my code.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That got rid of 2 errors. But I still get "TextView cannot be resolved to a type" in "Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText()" and "Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration" at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Tip: Organize imports - Use `Ctrl(or cmd)-Shift-o`, if you are using eclipse. This will remove unused imports and add necessary ones.

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution for this is just close that class after declaring that COUNTRIES ...
Then the code will be as follows

```
 package com.hellolistview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));

   ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
       // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   });
 }

    static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
    "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
    "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
    "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
    "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
    "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
    "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
    "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
    "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
    "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
    "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
    "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
    "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
    "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
    "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
    "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
    "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
    "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
    "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
    "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
    "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
    "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
    "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
    "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
    "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
    "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
    "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
    "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
    "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
    "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
    "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
    "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
    "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
    "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
    "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
     };
}
```